# how to reset the html dropdown list value to its orignal value when mouse move to next option

Tags: html, jsp, drop-down-menu, reset

actually my problem is...

i using dropdown list in my jsp page.
this dropdown list will have in a for loop.

example....

```
<% 
   int count1=0;
   for(int i=0;i<5;i++) {
   count1++;
%>

<div><input class="no" type="radio" name="companycode" id="<%=count1%>" value ="<%=count1%>"><%=count1%>
     <select class="none" name="cgccode" id="cgccode<%=count1%>">
     <option value="">-select-</option>
     <option value="google">GOOGLE</option>
     <option value="ibm">IBM</option>
     <option value="oracle">ORACLE</option>
     <option value="infosys">INFOSYS</option>
    </select></div>
<%
    } 
 %>
```

so, now my problem is,

suppose now i am selecting first radio button, and then i have select the first dropdown list value to IBM.
but after that, i am selecting second radio button (without submitting the previous dropdown list value). and i am selecting to second dropdown value.

but here the first dropdown list does not comes to its previous state. and the selected data is looking as same.

so, i need to change it to its previous state. when i am moving to another radio button.

pls help. i need the solution code. i have tried many ways but its not possible.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously, it won't work unless you use some JavaScript to reset the previous one.

Comment: please provide me that javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Since everything you do in your scenario is done at client side, in the browser, without any communication to the server, you need to use JavaScript to detect when a radio button value is changed, and set back the other drop-down selections to their default value.

Comment: how can i wrote? actually in the list box options, i retriving values from database. how to again use the default value? i dont want to use ajax. is there any javascript function?

Comment: i planning to do one thing, when ever i am clicking new radio button, then i will save the current value in session, then i will reload the page, and finally i will get the current position form the session and i will place the cursor there. but how to store the current position? html/javascript variable cannot be assigned to java session. then how? pls give me good solution with code..